# A better way to execute multiple MySQL commands using shell script

Tags: mysql, bash, shell

I would like to write a *.sh script to execute multiple MySQL commands.

Currently, what I can do is something like the following

```
mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password -e "drop database $dbname;"
mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password -e "create database $dbname;"
mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password -e "another MySQL command"
...
```

Is there a way to avoid typing `mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password -e` every time I want to execute a MySQL command?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think you can execute MySQL statements from a text file, for example

here is the cmds.txt file which contains MySQL commands:

```
select colA from TableA;
select colB from TableB;
select colC from TableC;
```

To execute them using shell script, type

```
mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password db_dbname < cmds.txt
```

This way, you separate your MySQL commands from your shell script.

You may want your script to display progress information to you. For this you can invoke mysql with "--verbose" option.

For more information, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-batch-commands.html

Comment: All of your answers are great. I choose EricWang's answer because I think this is the most structured way of doing this job.

Comment: Can you say me if this solution executes each statement in a separate transaction?

Comment: @Mike i think yes

Answer (score 32):

You can use a single multiquery:

```
mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password -e "drop database $dbname;create database $dbname;another MySQL command;"
```

Simply write all your queries seperated by `;`. They will be run one after the other.

Comment: All of your answers are great. I choose EricWang's answer because I think this is the most structured way of doing this job.

Comment: somehow that stopped working!

Answer (score 23):

Note that you can also use a HERE doc to have the queries within the same script:

```sh
mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password db_dbname <<'EOF'
select colA from TableA;
select colB from TableB;
select colC from TableC;
EOF
```

Note that I've used `'EOF'` rather than `EOF` in the first line in order to prevent the contents of the script to disable parameter substitution (especially the `` ` `` can be problematic)

Also note that there should **not be any whitespace before the final `EOF`** (except if you use `<<-` rather than `<<` -- in that case leading tab characters are stripped):

```sh
mysql -h$host -u$user -p$password db_dbname <<- 'EOF'
↠select colA from TableA;
↠select colB from TableB;
↠select colC from TableC;
↠EOF
```

*(Replace the `↠` with a tab character).*

For more info on the HERE doc syntax, see [the bash documentation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html).

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution! Using bash, I was receiving an error if I put a tab character before the ending EOF but without it, all went well.

Comment: Not worked for me. i am trying on the win 10 `cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin && mysql.exe  -u admin -padmin123  <<'EOF' select 'IMPORT_DONE' AS IMPORT_STATUS 
EOF`  Its Saying  ``'EOF' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.``

Answer (score 13):

There are several ways, in linux you have:

From the mysql cli:

```
mysql> source mycmds.sql
```

Using Pipes:

```
echo "SELECT ..; INSERT ..;" | mysql ...
```

Executing commands from a file using pipes or redirection:

```
cat file.sql | mysql ... OR mysql .. < file.sql
```

Comment: All of your answers are great. I choose EricWang's answer because I think this is the most structured way of doing this job.

Comment: The most complete answer. (It contains the answer of EricWang apart from `--version` for progress information.) Also using `.sql` as ending for SQL should be preferred over generic `.txt` to avooid loss of information (unless dynamic format detection is supported).

Answer (score 0):

Different from other answers that reduce repetition, but
there are ways to **reduce options**(user, host ... `-u`, `-p`, `-h` ...) from each line command

2 ways i know.

---

#### 1. use `my.cnf` file

you can store your user information in option files (e.g ~/.my.cnf or etc)

```
[client] 
user=your_username
password=your_password
# database=database_name
```

then you can just run `mysql` command with one option `-e` and query

```bash
mysql -e "drop database $dbname;"
mysql -e "create database $dbname;"
mysql -e "another MySQL command"
```

---

#### 2. use `mysql_config_editor`

you can save login informations with `mysql_config_editor`

```bash
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=mypath1 --host=localhost --user=root --password
```

then run command just with login-path option

```bash
mysql --login-path=mypath1 -e "drop database $dbname;"
mysql --login-path=mypath1 -e "create database $dbname;"
mysql --login-path=mypath1 -e "another MySQL command"
```