# How to correctly query the mysql database from bash script?

Tags: mysql, bash

I've been trying to correctly create a user and database for an hour using the bash script, but I'm still getting error messages. I paste the code below. I will be grateful for your help!

```
#!/bin/bash

username="useursur"
passworduser="dnfndfvjdngdg"

sudo mysql -u $username -p$passworduser <<EOF
    CREATE USER 'wpdb'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'fsafdasdfsadfasdf';
    CREATE DATABASE wpdb;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wpdb.* TO 'wpdb';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
EOF
```

I changed the command to

```
sudo mysql -u $username -p$passworduser -e "CREATE USER 'wpdb'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'fsafdasdfsadfasdf';CREATE DATABASE wpdb;GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wpdb.* TO 'wpdb';FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
```

As a result I get this error:

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1133 (42000) at line 1: Can't find any matching row in the user table
```

Comment: What are the error messages?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32869275/a-better-way-to-execute-multiple-mysql-commands-using-shell-script

Comment: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'wpdb'@'localhost'

Comment: mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1133 (42000) at line 3: Can't find any matching row in the user table

Comment: Put the password in `~/.my.cnf`, not on the commandline!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the user and host when you GRANT.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wpdb.* TO 'wpdb';
```

Should be:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wpdb.* TO 'wpdb'@'localhost';
```